# Can I tell if a 4 Mbps ADSL connection will work given my modem stats?

Tags: internet, adsl, adsl2+

I use telephone company provided ADSL. Currently I have a 2 Mbps plan. They offer a 4 Mbps plan but they say whether I can get the 4 Mbps speed depends on how far I am from the telephone exchange. So apparently the bottleneck lies in the last mile connectivity link and what speeds it can sustain.

They are going to send a technician to test but I hate waiting and most of the guys they send are quite clueless.

Meanwhile, I was wondering whether from the decibel / SNR (Signal to Noise Ratio) stats on my ADSL Modem / Router (DLink) I can make an educated guess as to whether 4 Mbps is viable for me or not.

Any thoughts?
[image]

Comment: Well internet speed depends on many factors. The distance from the exchange, the condition of the telephone cables before it reaches your house. The condition of the cables inside your house. The router you use. How the ISP manages the lines. You can't tell for sure. The difference between 2 and 4 is so little that even if you get 3 or 2.5 it will still be an improvement

Comment: @D.A Thanks! Any idea what the max ADSL speeds can be? And is there any correlation to be drawn from the hardware parameters that I uploaded?

Comment: The data you posted cannot tell what speed your router can support. DLink's routers can easily support speeds over 100 Mbps. It depends on the model. Now for the speed in your area that is something that your ISP can tell you. I have lived in places that maximum speed was 6-7 Mbps, now I have 50 Mbps. My university had broadband that reached 500 Mbps. I all depends on whether fibre cables have been set up in your area and smaller exchanges in close distances

Comment: @D.A Thanks again! Sorry, I wasn't clear. I didn't mean my DLink Router is the bottleneck. I meant is it possible to judge based on the SNR / dB / attenuation and other line properties (as revealed by the DLink Router's interface) as to what the max speed capabilities of the line may be? After all, the max speed is related to the channel properties, right? Is there a certain max attenuation or a min SNR below which certain speeds may not be possible?

Comment: I think this can answer your question. [SNR](https://www.speedguide.net/faq/what-is-considered-good-dsl-noise-margin-snr-355), [Attenuation](https://www.speedguide.net/faq/what-is-considered-good-dsl-line-attenuation-371)

Answer (score 1):

> Can I tell if a 4 Mbps ADSL connection will work given my modem stats?

Yes.
The modem stats clearly indicate that the current connection is already 4 Mbps,
 i.e. `Down Stream  4319 kbps`.

> Currently I have a 2 Mbps plan.

Then either you're getting a faster service than what you're paying for, or the ISP has already upgraded your service prior to the service call.

Answer (score 0):

I found a tool here that calculates the max speed possible in Mbps from the attenuation in dB

https://www.speedguide.net/dsl_speed_calc.php
[image]

More details are on here:

http://www.htxt.co.za/2014/01/19/check-adsl-lines-maximum-supported-speed/

Another useful  thumbrule is here:

https://www.giantstride.gr/snr-margin-adsl/

[image]